# Ubuntu SDK: Error with First App

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, html5

I am just starting to develop with the ubuntu sdk.

I created a default html5 project, and I havent changed anything.

This is the error:

```
Starting ubuntu-html5-app-launcher --www=/home/ryan/Documents/Ubuntu Workspace/MyFirstApp/www --inspector
Ignoring argument:  "Workspace/MyFirstApp/www" 
WWW folder not found or not a proper directory:  "/home/ryan/Documents/Ubuntu" 
ubuntu-html5-app-launcher exited with code 1
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in the space in your path.  The launcher only sees the first part of the path as the `www` argument, and rightly notices that this isn't a directory in which it could find an index.html file.  It also helpfully points out that it got the second half of the path as an additional argument, but doesn't know what to do with it.

You can fix this with one of the following:

1. Escaping the space in the path by preceding it with a backslash.
2. Quoting the path.
3. Not using spaces in your paths.

I recommend #3.